# Jquery Ajax request throwing a parse error for image response

Tags: jquery

On load of the page My requirement is that i need to load the images asynchronously , so that the flow will not stop even if the images aren't loaded .
I have got the image data in a json format

```
 {
        "image": [
            {
                "name": "bigsamosa.jpeg"
            },
            {
                "name": "cokebottle.jpg"
            },
            {
                "name": "coketin.jpg"
            },
            {
                "name": "HotChips.jpg"
            },
            {
                "name": "pepsi200ml.jpg"
            },
            {
                "name": "pepsibottle.jpg"
            }
        ]
    }
```

For each elemnt in the array , i am making an ajax request with empty url and and on success function i am creating the  image dynamcally

But each time , i am getting parse error in ajax request .

This is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5C77S/

could anybody please help me

Comment: Your Ajax request suppose to go to error. Since there is nothing to return from the ajax call. There should be something it got to return on success.

Comment: Is it possible to manipulate that somehow ??

Comment: Why are you making any ajax call? Can you really fetch images by ajax? A parse error simply means that the data type of your ajax request does not match the data type of the response returned.

Comment: I am making an Ajax call , only because i need to load the images asynchonusly .

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: can you please post code snippet of the page which you are calling via AJAX ?

Comment: Please refer to the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5C77S/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images in "img" tags are loaded asynchronously by default. The browser doesn't stop parsing a page of html when it makes a request for an image. So all you need to do is put "img" tags in your page for each of your images.

Comment: Thank you very much , how can i prove that the images are loaded asynchronusly .

Comment: display some text in an element underneath your images. You will see the text displayed before all the images have loaded. If you include the correct width and height settings in your img tags the browser will reserve the correct amount of space in the layout of the page and the text wont jump around so much as the images load.